# Memory usage in Spark stand alone setup

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-computing

I have a spark setup with a single worker having 6 cores. Now I broadcast an object x to the worker. 
I have three questions -

1. For a map reduce job will 6 copies of my obj x will be generated or a single copy of x will be shared by all the cores ?
2. What will be the life cycle of x i.e; when will it get destroyed. I'm asking because this object x takes up good amount of memory.
3. Is there some other way to share an object among all the 6 cores if I read that object from a file.

Comment: if its a stand alone setup and you have got a single machine ..there is no need to use broadcast variables.Broadcast variables are generally used to send out messages to multiple nodes.

Comment: Yeah I understand that. But then How can I save memory as all the processes will then have a copy of the same object which blows up the memory. Since it is a read only object , is there a way I can save memory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadcast data is transmitted and stored once per executor (java process) not once per core.  In other words if you have a single node, and you set **spark.executor.instances** set to 2, and **spark.executor.cores** set to 3 you will end up with two java processes on the node where each process has a copy of your data.  This is one of the benefits of using broadcasting instead of just passing the data into your executor code using closures.

As for the life cycle, the broadcast data will be removed when the broadcast handle on the driver no longer has any references to it.  This also means after any tasks using that broadcast data have been run.  If you watch the spark logs you will see messages along the lines of "Broadcast removed" when this happens.

Comment: is there a way I can save that memory ? because that object will be replicated among all the processes ?

Comment: If you only have 1 executor process per node (with multiple cores) then you only have one copy in RAM on each node.  How can you reduce it to less than 1?  Any other memory savings would need to come from you reducing the size of your shared object.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check the memory and time consumption statistics by changing the num of executors and num of cores per executor.